# Cholesterol level in your body and Running

Tags: running, breathing, cholesterol

I easily get out of breath when I am:

1. Climbing stairs - not quickly but normally
2. When I go for jogging in ground (stadium/park)

But when I run on treadmill I can easily run for continuous 15 mins at 1 level up incline.

**Does this still shows that I have high cholesterol levels in body?** I am 31 years old, I am not skinny, I am not heavy build, I am not fat. I weigh 176 pounds.

I do running, heavy lifts on 'n' off, not regular basis.

Comment: When running on a treadmill you run at a steady pace while at the stadium/park your pace may be faster than on the treadmill or inconsistent, which affects your endurance. If you're concerned about high cholesterol, you should check with a doctor.

Comment: Got it. Feeling out of breath, could happen with anyone who has low cholesterol levels and high?

Answer (score 1):

No, cholesterol levels being high is not a direct contributor to being out of breath or short of breath.

However, one possibility is that if you do have high cholesterol, you have some of the associated problems such as narrowing of the arteries due to plaque buildup, and the reduced blood flow can create the short of breath feeling.

I would advise you to go get a physical and have them do a cholesterol test.